# Process ran as different user - web service call

Tags: c#, authentication, process, profile

I have a legacy piece of software, that used to run from `user1@domain.com` account on machine X. This piece of software, amongst other things, makes a webservice call, using `MSXML`. The call is authenticated by passing `user1@domain.com` credentials with NTLM. All webservice communications work seamlessly.

I now have to run this piece of software under `user2@domain.com` account on the same machine X. To preserve current setup and to avoid configuring additional delegation, I wrote a wrapper, which uses `Process.Start()` to run the legacy software as `user1@domain.com`. Now, when the webservice call is made, the credential box pops up, despite fact the legacy soft is running as `user1@domain.com`. Even if I provide username/password combination, this gets rejected by the webservice.

Unless I log in as `user1@domain.com`, then switch accounts to `user2@domain.com`, leaving the previous session in the background - in which case all works fine.

Can anyone shed a light on this? Does invoking a process require user profile to be active in some shape or form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rejoining the machine to the domain has resolved.